# Pandas Grouper "Cumulative" sum()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I'm trying to calculate the cumulative total for the next 4 weeks.

Here is an example of my data frame

```
d = {'account': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
     'volume': [25, 60, 40, 100, 50, 100, 40, 50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['week_starting'] = pd.date_range('05/02/2021',
                                    periods=8,
                                    freq='W')
```

```
df['volume_next_4_weeks'] = [225, 250, 290, 290, 240, 190, 90, 50]
df['volume_next_4_weeks_cumulative'] = ['(25+60+40+100)', '(60+40+100+50)', '(40+100+50+100)', '(100+50+100+40)', '(50+100+40+50)', '(100+40+50)', '(40+50)', '(50)']
df.head(10)
```

[dataframe_table_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uDgL.png)

I would to find a way to calculate the cumulative amount by pd.Grouper freq = 4W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['volume_next_4_weeks']  = [sum(df['volume'][i:i+4]) for i in range(len(df))]
```

For the other column showing the addition as `string`, I have stored the values in a list using the same logic above but not applying sum and then joining the list elements as `string`:

```
df['volume_next_4_weeks_cumulative'] = [df['volume'][i:i+4].to_list() for i in range(len(df))]
df['volume_next_4_weeks_cumulative'] = df['volume_next_4_weeks_cumulative'].apply(lambda row: ' + '.join(str(x) for x in row))
```

Now as you mentioned you have different multiple accounts and you want to do it separately for all of them, create a custom function and then use `groupby` and `apply` to create the columns:

```
def create_mov_cols(df):
    df['volume_next_4_weeks']  = [sum(df['volume'][i:i+4]) for i in range(len(df))]
    df['volume_next_4_weeks_cumulative'] = [df['volume'][i:i+4].to_list() for i in range(len(df))]
    df['volume_next_4_weeks_cumulative'] = df['volume_next_4_weeks_cumulative'].apply(lambda row: ' + '.join(str(x) for x in row))
    return df
```

Apply the function to the DataFrame:

```
df = df.groupby(['account']).apply(create_mov_cols)
```

Comment: Shivan Roy it works. Thank you very much.
How do I group it by account? 

I my example, I just have one account, but in the real problem I do have more accounts with the same week_starting

Comment: You can create a custom function with the code I have mentioned in my answer, and then use `groupby(['account']).apply(custom_func)` to get the desired result. Please check the edit,  I've done it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Shivan Roy.
It worked just fine. I wonder where I may find courses to learn more about these functions.

Comment: @KleitonMarquesDosReis I'm glad it helped you. There are a lot of sources, the pandas documentation is a good source, apart from that there are several good free channels on YouTube you could search: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wb2Tp35dZ-I  , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txMdrV1Ut64 . These are two videos, you can explore their channel as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['volume_next_4_weeks'] = df[['week_starting', 'volume']][::-1].rolling(window='28D', on='week_starting').sum()[::-1]['volume']
```

`28D` is used instead of `4W` since latter is not a fixed frequency.

Comment: im0j it also worked very well. 
As I mentioned above, how can I group by account?